# How Can i Check Solr master is communicating with Solr Slave

Tags: solr, master-slave

I Have done Solr master-slave configuration for setting up solr server. I can access master url also. Also i did master-slave replication configuration on "solrconfig.xml" and started services on both master and slave server .
But i don't know master-slave replication is working or not. 
How can i check that master slave is working?

Answer (score 1):

If you [go to the replication tab](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Replication+Screen) under the Solr Admin page, you'll find an overview of the current version of the index replicated to your slave (together with the most recent version available at the master). You can also [manually call the endpoint](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#Not_replicating._Admin_show_index_version_but_.2Freplication.3Fcommand.3Dindexversion__returns_0) for the indexversion: `/replication?command=indexversion`

Make a commit to the master server and verify that the client has updated its version after the replication delay.

You can also tail the log file to see replication take place (it's logged at the INFO level IIRC), or (the most manual version) search with a few seconds intervals to see if the new document shows up in the replicated index.

Comment: In "replication tab" :    Master (Replicable) 
-
-
-

Comment: So what does the page under 'core' look like?